# Thymeleaf form action don‘t skip to

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

controller

```
@GetMapping("/form")
    public ModelAndView createForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("title", "创建用户");
        return new ModelAndView("users/form","userModel",model);
    }
```

form

```
<form action="/users" th:action="@{/users}" method="POST" th:object="${userModel.user}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{id}">
    name：
    <input type="text" name="name" th:value="*{name}">
    <br>
    email：
    <input type="text" name="email" th:value="*{email}">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The form did not jump while I clicked submit.
It returned an error.
[image]

I want to know how to modify it here to make it right

After remove action="/users"，rebuild the project,
submit the form,the error still there.
[image: after remove action="/users"]

Answer (score 0):

The `action` attribute appears twice. You need to remove `action='/users'` and keep the `th:action`

Also update your question with the stacktrace in the console when the error happens

Comment: After remove action='/users',It still reports an error.The error  is the same as yesterday